# live wallpaper looks larger on htc X but looks ok on s3 and nexus 7 though the resolution is the same

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, live-wallpaper, htc-android

I have a live wallpaper which works on high res devices, specifically on the galaxy s3 and the nexus 7.
I've tested it on an htc one x which is also a 720p device, but the wallpaper seems to be scaled up.
I don't own an htc x so I can't check what screen size the wallpaper gets..
The wallpaper works on openGL 2.0 so it might be the camera z value, but why would it look different than the nexus 7 or the s3?
Does anyone have a clue of what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Edit: this is the view initialization code:

```
    // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
    // such as screen rotation
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Create the projection matrix so that it converts the 3000px grid to actual screen dimensions, centered (letterboxed)
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -(width / 3000.0f) / 2.0f, (width / 3000.0f) / 2.0f, -(height / 3000.0f) / 2.0f, (height / 3000.0f) / 2.0f, 3, 7);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0, 3.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
```

`

I use a 3000x3000 pixel "virtual" grid for element placement, then just letterbox it using the projection matrix. It works very well on N7 or S3, but the Z value looks off on One X.

All of the vertices are set to Z of 0.

Comment: What is the code for viewport/view matrices initialization? What values does it operate with?

Comment: not sure on live wall papers honestly, but static wallpapers are often distorted on HTC phones because the sense home screen does not have wallpaper scrolling, so instead of fitting on several homescreen areas, the wallpaper is forced into one wallpaper area.